# Is it possible to fake a SMB network mounted folder as a native folder?

Tags: mount, indexing

I have an HDD hooked up to a linux TV receiver (Vu Solo) with a lot of movies in one folder. This device and my (Synology) NAS are in the same local network. The NAS contains a media indexing service that scans specific native folders (e.g. /video) on the NAS.

So far I have shared the folder on the receiver (containing the movies) via SMB and mounted it in within the /video folder on the NAS in a separate folder. Unfortunately, the indexing service of the NAS ignores that mounted folder. My guess is I would have to pretend somehow that this is not a mounted directory but just another native folder on the NAS. Is there any chance of doing this?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps indexing stops when crossing a filesystem.
What might work is to explicitly add the mount point directory as a second place to index, even though it is under `/video`.

In the DSM GUI you can add new directories to scan by going through: control
panel, system, indexing service, media indexing, indexed folder, create,
folder: select, ok, save.

If this doesn't work, you can resort to the command line. You must enable ssh then login. You can then run `synoindex -R /volume1/video/myvusolo` to index that directory. Use `synoindex -h` to see the other options like `-A` to add a directory to the places to index. Search the web for this command to find helper scripts that some people have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably is that the software does not scan the whole disk, and has to be configured to scan that particular directory.

What you can ask can be done for sure, either using NFS or most probably iSCSI.

The bad news is that the kernel has to support those services as far as I remember. No idea if Synology supports that as a client.